# взаимное расположение img в css

Tags: css, вёрстка, изображения, адаптивная-верстка, html

Задача: расставить изображения так, как показано в рисунке во вложении ( два друг под другом, а третье - справа).

Форма изображений ТАКАЯ ЖЕ, как показана на рисунке (т.е. высота 3-го изображения равна суммарной высоте 1 и 2 + расстояние между 1 и 2; ширина тоже у всех соответствующая)

Были попытки написать такой код, но высота 3 очень сильно вылезала за сумму высот 1 и 2, хотя изначально у изображений относительная высота/ширина правильная:

```css
.thumb {
  height: 500px;
}

.thumb img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

.box div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p class="thumb">
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/300" alt="picsum.photos" title="placeholder picsum.photos">
      <br>
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/301" alt="picsum.photos" title="placeholder picsum.photos">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="thumb">
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/302" alt="picsum.photos" title="placeholder picsum.photos">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Осуществить это все нужно адаптивно.

[image: таким образом должны располагаться фото]

Comment: Используйте для решения `width: calc();` `height: calc();`, на сегодня > 90% поддержка браузерами [https://caniuse.com/#search=calc()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.gallery{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:400px;
  max-width:100%;
}
.gallery__column{
  width:calc(50% - 7.5px);
  flex:0 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.gallery__img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  margin:0 0 15px;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
}
.gallery__img:last-child{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery__column">
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/300" class="gallery__img" />
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/301" class="gallery__img" />
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__column">
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/302" class="gallery__img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1)Зачем туда добавлять `<p>`? Подпись к картинкам? 2) Вроде не должен. Скиньте сюда, что у вас получилось.

Comment: Я не знаю как свёрстан ваш блок с галереей и текстом. Без кода ничем помочь не смогу.